# How to use own DAO class with table config file

Tags: android, ormlite

In ORMLite, want to switch from annotation-based DB table definition to a table config file. I have created an `ormlite_config.txt` file as described [here](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_4.html#Config-Optimization), and I use it in my `DatabaseHelper` constructor:

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION, R.raw.ormlite_config);
}
```

As I can see from the logs, the configuration for every table is loaded successfully. However, I want to keep using custom DAO classes (subclasses of `BaseDaoImpl`) for most of my tables, in analogy to the annotation `@DatabaseTable(daoClass = MyDaoClass.class)`.

Is it possible to use a custom DAO class in combination with a table config file at all? Something like:

```
# --table-start--
dataClass=com.example.model.Product
daoClass=com.example.db.ProductDao
tableName=product
# --table-fields-start--
# --field-start--
...
```

Comment: Just create the DAO by hand with your connectionsource. Afterwards register the DAO with DaoManager.registerDao(connectionSource, dao).

Answer (score 1):

I think this could help you with your problem: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/ormlite-android/DAO/ormlite-android/tYHcLjv8xtQ/6kKl5Vnwy6EJ

So with your config file, DAO creation is heavily speed up and you can create your DAO just like before and register it with the DaoManager.

Comment: Ok, but for `BaseDaoImpl`, I need either an annotated class as a constructor argument or a `DatabaseTableConfig`, which I don't have because I define the table config in the text file and not in code.

Comment: As far as I understand it, it would be perfectly fine to use `DaoManager.createDao(cs, MyDomainClass.class)`, because the DaoManager will know where to look for your config file, because of your configuration in OrmLiteConfigUtil (see classes, that you give to `writeConfigFile()`)

Answer (score 0):

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION,
                R.raw.ormlite_config);
    }

*and config file is*

# --table-start--
dataClass=com.exito.patelsdrive.MessageList
tableName=message_store
# --table-fields-start--
# --field-start--
fieldName=messageId
columnName=message_id
generatedId=true
# --field-end--
# --field-start--
fieldName=message
columnName=msg_content
# --field-end--
# --table-end--
```